# A criterion for second countability

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.

Assume for any arbitrary topological base $\mathcal{E}$ of $\tau$ we have that: the Borel sigma algebras coming  form $\mathcal{E}$ and $\tau$ are the same. Can we conclude that  $X$ is **second countable** ?!

This question is also asked  when $X$ is  a locally convex space. Please read the comments below.

Comment: What about non-countable discrete sets?

Comment: @WilleLiou The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the power-set, but the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the basis of singletons is the countable-co-countable $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: An example: 
Let $X$ be a non-countable set. We equip $X$ with the topology whose open sets consist of $\emptyset$ and those subsets $U\subseteq X$ with $|X\setminus U| < \infty$. Then any basis generates the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra but $X$ is not second countable.

Comment: @WilleLiou It was really interesting. Thank you very much.

Comment: This question seems to be much more challenging (and  mysterious) when, $X$ is considered as a  *locally convex* topological vector space  i.e. $\tau$ induced by  a family of seminorms on $X$. It would be great to have an answer in this particular case.

Comment: @GABB Are you sure it makes sense to add these tags to the question the way it is now? I believe you should ask a separate question about topological vector spaces

Comment: Probably you are right. So I do now.

Comment: @WilleLiou: standard word for "non-countable" is "uncountable" :)

Comment: @GABB when a question is so easy that it's answered in comments then I think it's reasonable to modify the question to make it more interesting. So I'd rather suggest to do so (and add relevant tags). I don't mean ask a second question. Still, the question can include a discussion reflecting the input from previous comments.

Comment: I would suggest instead that the commenters post their answer as an answer, rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample to this question (and its locally convex version) is any non-metrizable (locally convex) space $X$, which is hereditarily Lindelof. The hereditary Lindelofness of $X$ implies that any open set is a countable union of basic open sets and this implies that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by any base of the topology coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

As for an example of non-metrizable hereditarily Lindelof spaces, take any metrizable separable locally convex space with a weaker non-metrizable topology. 
Being a continuous image of a second-countable space, such space will have countable network and hence will be hereditarily Lindelof.

For example, you can take any infinite-dimensional separable Banach space endowed with the weak topology. It will be not metrizable but hereditarily Lindelof.

The function spaces $C_p(X)$ over cosmic spaces $X$ have countable network and hence are hereditarily Lindelof. The function spaces $C_k(X)$ with compact-open topology over $\aleph_0$-spaces $X$ have countable $k$-network and hence are hereditarily Lindelof.

The locally convex space $\mathbb R^\infty$, which is inductive limit of an increasing sequence of finite-dimensional spaces, has countable network and hence is hereditarily Lindelof and not metrizable.

So, there plenty of examples. But one can modify the question replacing the second countability by the hereditary Lindelofness:

**Problem.** *Is a (locally convex) topological space hereditary Lindelof if the $\sigma$-algebra generated by any base of the topology coincides with the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets?*

**Remark.** The example given by @Wille Liou in the comment to the original question is hereditarily Lindelof (even hereditarily compact), but not Hausdorff.

In fact, the hereditary Lindelofness admits the following characterization:

**Theorem.** *A topological space $X$ is hereditary Lindelof if and only if for any subspace $Y\subset X$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by any base of the topology of $Y$ coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$.*

Comment: Could you please give a bit more concerning the last Theorem. Indeed why the coincidences of $\sigma$-algebras implies the hereditary Lindelof property.

Comment: @AliBagheri See Exercise 3.12.7(b) in "General Topology" of Engelking.

Comment: I could not get how this exercise helps us to find the result. Could you please write a bite more.

Comment: @AliBagheri Have you read this Exercise 3.12.7(b)? Could you formulate what is proved in this exercise?