# An equivalent condition for second countable locally convex spaces

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a locally convex topological vector space.

Assume for any arbitrary topological base $\mathcal{E}$ of $\tau$ we have that: the Borel sigma algebras coming  from $\mathcal{E}$ and $\tau$ are the same. Can we conclude that  $X$ is **second countable** ?!

Generally, if $X$ is just a topological space, the answer will be  negative. See [enter link description here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286332/a-criterion-for-second-countability)